# MemoryError trying to convert Numpy 2D arrays into a 3D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have some trouble converting some amount (in this case, 153) of Numpy 2D arrays into a 3D array (these 2D arrays represent gray images - i.e. 2048x2048x1 - in order to deal with an image sequence instead of a set of 2D images). I need this to obtain the signal formed by each pixel value over time (which should be convenient with Numpy, once this problem is solved).

My code is (pretty much) the following :

```
zdim = len(imglist) # 'imglist' a Python list of the path for each image I need to process
windowspan = 512
xmin = ymin = 2
xmax = ymax = xmin + windowspan

sequence = []
for i in range(zdim):
    hdulist = fits.open(imglist[i],'readonly') # allow to open FITS image files
    hdr = hdulist[0].header['DATE-OBS'] # fetch the image date/time
    img = fc.readfitsimg(imglist[i]) # return a np ndarray (2D)
    patch = img[ymin:ymax, xmin:xmax] # take a small of the original image
    print("patchSize : " + str(patch.size*4))
    sequence.append(patch) # adding to the list
    print("it : " + str(i))
sequence = np.array(sequence) # transform to numpy array
```

The interpreter returns a MemoryError after about 85 iterations...

Anyone would have any hints of what's happening ? (See some details below)

Some others details :
- I'm using WinPython 32 bits (portable), because I cannot install a 'proper' Python distribution (I switched between Python 2.7.9.4 and 3.4.3.3 for testing purpose)
- I'm forced to use a 32-bits Windows 7, on a PC which has 4GB, so 3.5GB usable / I've tried executing my script on another computer (Win7 64bits, 16GB of RAM)

Thanks for any help you could provide me with.

Comment: You should give the whole `MemoryError` backtrace, in particular on which line it happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [MemoryError](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html?highlight=memoryerror#exceptions.MemoryError) happens when your computer runs out of RAM memory. In this case, you seem to run out while adding all the images into a cube, when hitting the limit 85x512x512. If this was the only problem of the code, I would advice to use [memmap](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html) to save the results directly to the hard drive instead of in the RAM. The memmap option is also available when you open a fits file `fits.open(..., memmap=True)`. In that case, you only open the image in the disc, and read the parts you need, instead of loading the whole image in RAM.

But the real problem here, I suspect, is that you have been opening fits files without any closing at the end of the loop (hdu.close() in your case).

Comment: hi, small question: would the package "bcolz" be a solution for that ?

Comment: Just to let you know the 'memmap' technique isn't working because of the data type ( 'ValueError: Cannot load a memory-mapped image: BZERO/BSCALE/BLANK header keywords present. Set memmap=False.')

Comment: The problem is, in my case, if I want to have a vector of grayscale values for each pixel over time and use at the same time Numpy data structures, I will need to load everything into RAM (that's why I was using a patch much smaller than the original image). I forgot to mention that "fits" is an alias for the module "Pyfits", where there is no method called 'close'...
 
If MemoryError pops, the allocated RAM should be full. How would you explained that allocated RAM would be the same between 2 different OSes (32 vs. 64bits, and respectively 3.5 vs.16GB of RAM) ?

Comment: you mean you have the same error on W7 64 bit 16Go ram ?

Comment: Hi Paradox. Pyfits returns an object HDUlist, which has indeed a close method: http://pyfits.readthedocs.org/en/v3.3.0/api_docs/api_hdulists.html#pyfits.HDUList. I have reason to believe that you are using memory by not closing them at the end of the loop, even more so if you say the images are much bigger than those 512x512. Try it, and see if it's true that you'll reach further than image 85.